# ReactiveMongo - Aggregation Framework - first batch behavior not clear

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

I have a question about cursor batches.

In the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) it is stated:

> cursor.batchSize(size)
>   Specifies the number of documents to return in each batch of the response from the MongoDB instance.
>   In most cases, modifying the batch size will not affect the user or the application, as the mongo shell and most drivers return results as if MongoDB returned a single batch.

and in the [ReactiveMongo documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html) we have:

> About the type `AggregationResult` the property `documents` has been renamed to `firstBatch`, to clearly indicate it returns the first batch from result **(which is frequently the single one).** *[my emphasis]*.

My questions are:

1. In what situation the first batch returned is the single one and in what situations it is not?
2. How can I control that?

Neither ReactiveMongo, nor MongoDB documentations seem to be clear on the topic.

Comment: Perhaps they mean that in practice, many aggregation queries return a small number of documents  - a small enough number to fit in a single batch?

Comment: If firstBatch() returns only a partial number of the documents how can I access the rest of them?

Comment: Let me rephrase. I have an aggregation query that returns a result. I want to be sure that the result includes ALL the data and not only a first batch.

Comment: You could have a look at the documentation http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html#aggregated-streams